# Flutter: strange behaviour of Dismissible when using a "responsive" design

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, dismissible

I'm facing a rather surprising behaviour of the Dismissible component these days.
I'm using the very same widget, AirportWidget, in its own page when using a narrow screen:

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(…),
      body:  RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
        child:  AirportWidget(…),
      onRefresh: _refreshAirportList)
    )
```

or as the right part of the screen (right component in a row with the list of components occupying the left part) when displayed on a wide screen:

```
   Row(children: <Widget>[
     MyAirportsListWidget,
     ViewState.isLargeScreen ? Expanded(child: Card(child:AirportWidget(…)) : Container()])
```

Now my problem: my AirportWidget, the very same Widget in both cases, contains a Column of elements each embedded in a Dismissible. It all works perfectly when the AirportWidget is displayed on its own page, but it doesn't when displayed on the right side of a wide screen...
It still somehow recognises when a Dismissible element is swiped in the right direction (does nothing when swiped in the other), but instead of showing it disappearing in that direction and then calling the onDismissed method, it shows no animation and just jumps up to the top of the column (rebuilds the component I guess).

Rings a bell to someone from here, or do I need to come up with full details?

Best regards

More code details: It's a bit of a complicated design. The AirportWidget which contains the Dismissible is itself made of two tabs: the first tab to display airport weather (not relevant for us now, since it contains no Dismissible), and the second tab to display NOTAMs (airport informations). That's the one containing Dismissible elements.

```
class AirportWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  Airport _airport;
  int _currentIndex;

  AirportWidget(this._airport, {int index, Key key}) : super(key: key) {
    _currentIndex =  index != null? index : ViewState.airportSelectedTabIndex;
  }

  @override
  AirportWidgetState createState() => AirportWidgetState();

}

class AirportWidgetState extends State<AirportWidget> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  // Bottom tabs and active tab index
  List<Widget> _children;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _children = [
      AirportWeatherWidget(widget._airport),
      AirportNotamsWidget(widget._airport),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: widget._airport == null? noAirportScreen(context) : _children[widget._currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: themes.AppColors.CREAM_FONT,
        onTap: onTabTapped, // new
        currentIndex: widget._currentIndex, // new
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.filter_drama),
            title: new Text('WEATHER'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.library_books),
            title: new Text("NOTAMS"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      ViewState.airportSelectedTabIndex = index;
      widget._currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Now let's see the AirportNotamsWidget which contains the Dismissible elements:

```
class AirportNotamsWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  Airport _airport;

  AirportNotamsWidget(this._airport);

  @override
  AirportNotamsWidgetState createState() => AirportNotamsWidgetState();
}

class AirportNotamsWidgetState extends State<AirportNotamsWidget> {
 // final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();  // used for snackbar display

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> notamsWidgetsList = List<Widget>();
    Color nonSelectedStarColor = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light?
    themes.AppColors.LIGHT_GREY : themes.AppColors.CREAM_FONT;
    Color selectedStarColor = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light?
    themes.AppColors.YELLOW : themes.AppColors.DARK_YELLOW;

    Widget topRow = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: Text(widget._airport.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle)),
        Row( children: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: ViewState.dislplaySnowtams? Theme.of(context).accentColor :
          Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                ViewState.dislplaySnowtams = !ViewState.dislplaySnowtams;
              });
            }
          ),
          MaterialButton(child: Text(ViewState.displayRelevantNotamsOnly? "RLV" : "ALL"), minWidth: 40,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              ViewState.displayRelevantNotamsOnly = !ViewState.displayRelevantNotamsOnly;
            });
          }
        )
        ])
    ],);
    notamsWidgetsList.add(topRow);
    //     Text("NOTAMs view not yet implemented", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),


    notamsWidgetsList.add(Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor,
      child: Row(children: [Text("NOTAMS", style: TextStyle(color:
      Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light? themes.AppColors.LIGHT_GREY: themes.AppColors.CREAM_FONT,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:0, top: 3, bottom: 3), margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 6),
    ));

    if(widget._airport.normalNotamsList.isNotEmpty) {
      for(int i = 0; i < widget._airport.normalNotamsList.length; i++) {
        NOTAM notam = widget._airport.normalNotamsList[i];
          notamsWidgetsList.add(
           Dismissible(
             // unique key in order to be able to remove the item from a sublist and add it to another
              key: Key(notam.key + DateTime.now().toString()),
              background: Container(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(themes.DISMISSIBLE_TILES_BACKGROUND_LATERAL_PADDING, 0.0,
                    themes.DISMISSIBLE_TILES_BACKGROUND_LATERAL_PADDING, 0.0),
                  child: Column(children: [Text("NON"), Text("RELEVANT")], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,)
                ),
              ),
             child: Card(
               child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(child: Text(notam.id + " - " + notam.Subject + " " + notam.Modifier,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead)),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.star, color: notam.isStarred()?  selectedStarColor : nonSelectedStarColor),
                          onPressed: ()async {
                            setState(() {
                              widget._airport.toggleNotamStarred(notam);
                              PersistenceManager.updateNotam(notam);
                            });
                          }),
                      ]),
                    Text(ViewUtil.printNotamMessage(notam.message), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
                    Row(children:
                    [Text("From: " + ViewUtil.printDate(context, notam.startDate) + " " + ViewUtil.printTime(context, notam.startDate)
                      + "  To: " + ViewUtil.printDate(context, notam.endDate) + " " + ViewUtil.printTime(context, notam.endDate),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,)], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,),
                  ],
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                ),
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               ),
              ),
              direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                print("DISMISSED");
                    setState(() {
                      widget._airport.normalNotamsList.remove(notam);
                      widget._airport.nonRelevantNotamsList.add(notam);
                      notam.priority = NOTAM.PRIORITY_IRRELEVANT;
                      Util.sortNotamList(widget._airport.nonRelevantNotamsList);
                      PersistenceManager.updateNotam(notam);
                    });
                }
              ),
            );
      }
      notamsWidgetsList.add(Divider());
    }

    if(!ViewState.displayRelevantNotamsOnly) {
      if(widget._airport.nonRelevantNotamsList.isNotEmpty) {
        notamsWidgetsList.add(Text("NON OPERATION RELEVANT NOTAMs"));
        widget._airport.nonRelevantNotamsList.forEach((notam) {
            notamsWidgetsList.add(
              Dismissible(
                // unique key in order to be able to remove the item from a sublist and add it to another
                  key: Key(notam.key + DateTime.now().toString()),
                  background: Container(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(themes.DISMISSIBLE_TILES_BACKGROUND_LATERAL_PADDING, 0.0,
                        themes.DISMISSIBLE_TILES_BACKGROUND_LATERAL_PADDING, 0.0),
                      child: Text("RELEVANT"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(child: Text(notam.id + " - " + notam.Subject + " " + notam.Modifier,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead)),
                              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.star, color: notam.isStarred()?  selectedStarColor : nonSelectedStarColor),
                                onPressed: ()async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget._airport.toggleNotamStarred(notam);
                                    PersistenceManager.updateNotam(notam);
                                  });
                                }),
                            ]),
                          Text(ViewUtil.printNotamMessage(notam.message), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
                          Row(children:
                          [Text("From: " + ViewUtil.printDate(context, notam.startDate) + " " + ViewUtil.printTime(context, notam.startDate)
                            + "  To: " + ViewUtil.printDate(context, notam.endDate) + " " + ViewUtil.printTime(context, notam.endDate),
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,)], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,),
                        ],
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  )),
                  direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                      setState(() {
                        widget._airport.nonRelevantNotamsList.remove(notam);
                        widget._airport.normalNotamsList.add(notam);
                        notam.priority = NOTAM.PRIORITY_NORMAL;
                        Util.sortNotamList(widget._airport.normalNotamsList);
                        PersistenceManager.updateNotam(notam);
                      });
                    }
                  }
                ),
);

        });
      }
    }
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) =>
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: notamsWidgetsList,
              )
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the app in "wide screen" mode: when we select an airport in the list to the left, the two-tabbed details of the airport is displayed in the right half of the screen. Here we can see the NOTAM tab, with the problematic Dismissible cards.

[image]

When displayed in narrow screen mode as shown below, the same Dismissible cards are working perfectly

[image]

Comment: Please post the whole code where you used the Dismissible

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so fast Amon! I added the code details to my post :)